# Codeigniter 3 - HMVC, Phil Sturgeon Template Library Issue

Tags: php, methods, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to implement Phil Sturgeon Template Library in HMVC Codeingiter 3 structure site.

This is my tree folder:

[image: Folder Structure HMVC + PS Template Lib]

this is my controller file:

```
//public_html/application/modules/site/controllers/Home.php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller {

    public function construct(){
        parent::_construct();
    }

    public function index(){

        $this->template
                ->set_theme('default')
                ->set_layout('default')
                ->build('index', $data);

    }
}
```

but when I try to load my template and the index I've got this error messagge:

[image: Error Message]

Where I'm failing?

Comment: This one https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template? It's for codeigniter 2 not 3.

Comment: @Felippe Duarte. Thanks for your hint, there another solid, stable template library for CI3 HMVC? Thanks a lot